# How are intents dealt with when the service is stopped?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm new to android programming so these are probably dumb questions.  I've done some reading but can't quite get the answer.

I have a broadcast receiver with some intents registered from a service -

```
    receiver = new EventHandler();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED); // for calls
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

As I've removed the "setForeground" call I put in to keep my service running (as I don't want a status bar icon and I'm wondering if I'm being lazy with that approach), my service will now get killed off regularly and started up again usually a short time later (but sometimes I've seen it be 5 mins).

Question - as I've registered my intents programatically, how will Android know to send the intents I'm interested in if my process happens to be in the stopped state.  I'm assuming I'll miss some events.

I tried putting the intents in the manifest but I've read (and observed) that you can't use that technique for the battery changed intent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all, if you want to keep your service alive, you have to acquire a `WakeLock` from the `PowerManager` in `onCreate()` and release it in `onDestroy()`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

The OS might still destroy and recreate your service sometimes, but you don't have to worry about it being stopped for an extended period. (`startForeground()` doesn't guarantee it either, that your `Service` will stay alive after you applied keylock for example.)

If your service is destroyed, then the OS will still fire the `Intents` you just won't see them.

Comment: "If your service is destroyed, then the OS will still fire the Intents you just won't see them" - that answers my question.  It does sound like I need to keep my service alive as much as is possible. I didn't know about wake locks so thanks for that info - I will have a look at that.

Comment: be careful, adding wake lock will drain your battery :)

Comment: Presumably it's a "PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK" that I need?  All the other settings seem to be keeping the screen on which I certainly don't want!

Comment: @Superbiji - I see what you mean - it will prevent the CPU from going into deep sleep?  My service is designed to run all the time so that would kill the battery. Hmmm.  I might have to put some events in the manifest and just live with the battery changed one missing a few notifications.

Comment: Yes, you need a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` and if you just listen for the `Intent`s in your service you don't have to worry about it draining your battery. It won't make that much of a difference in power consumption

Answer (score 0):

Intent is a special late-binding mechanism in Android. Broadcast receivers, activities and services registers there intent filters in the system, and when an intent is fired, the system activates components that can handle this intent. Thus, if an intent filter is registered in the system, your component will be invoked. In case of static intent-filters in the system (those, that are declared in AndroidManifest.xml) the Android OS registers then during the start of the system. In case of dynamic intent-filters (that are declared in the code for broadcastreceivers) you need to register them after the boot. Thus, you can declare intent-filter for onBoot event and in this broadcast receiver you can declare your dynamic intents.

Answer (score 0):

About your service being killed and restarted, it is normal in android, especially when there is low memory. ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED can not be put in manifest but ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF can.
So you have put in a Service and make sure your event receiver running, put register in onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // battery
    registerReceiver(mBatteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
        Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    ...
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(mBatteryInfoReceiver);
}
```

and also dont forget to unregister, when your service intended to be stop

Comment: Hi - yes this is what I have done.  My concern is that if the battery changes when my service has been killed off, how is it going to get the notification?  As it's not in the manifest, I'm guessing Android won't know that I'm interested in that notification.  Thanks for the reply.  Peter.